# Результаты поиска - выводится только первый результат, хотя их два

Tags: php, mysql

Вот скрипт:

```
$terh = $_POST['tema'];
$jui  = $_POST['min'];
$uti  = $_POST['form'];
$reui = $_POST['vyp'] or die("Что-то не так.");

if (preg_match("/были/", $reui) && preg_match("/^игры/", $terh) && preg_match("/^100/", $jui) && preg_match("/^topline/", $uti)) {
    $dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $query = "SELECT `opisanie` FROM `parte` where vyp='были' limit 0,2";
    $res = mysql_query("$query;") or die("Что-то не так.");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res))
        $row1 = $row->opisanie;

    $equery = "SELECT `opisanie` FROM `parte` where minimum='100' limit 0,2";
    $eres = mysql_query("$equery;") or die("Что-то не так.");
    while ($erow = mysql_fetch_object($eres))
        $row2 = $erow->opisanie;

    $wquery = "SELECT `opisanie` FROM `bada` where format='top' limit 0,2";
    $wres = mysql_query("$wquery;") or die("Что-то не так.");
    while ($wrow = mysql_fetch_object($wres))
        $row3 = $wrow->opisanie;

    $squery = "SELECT `opisanie` FROM `bada` where tema='игры' limit 0,2";
    $ses = mysql_query("$squery;") or die("Что-то не так.");
    while ($srow = mysql_fetch_object($sres))
        $row4 = $srow->opisanie or die('ошибка');

    if ($row1 == $row2 && $row1 == $row3 && $row1 == $row4 or die('ошибка')) {
        echo $row1;
    }
}
```

В любых случаях выводится лишь один результат. Специально создал две одинаковых позиции (только поле "opisanie" разное). Все равно выводится только один результат. Как вывести два?

Comment: >> die("Что-то не так.");

Жесть.. :)

Comment: Что вы этим хотели сказать? Это всего лишь проверка на специальную инсценировку ошибки, хотя, в принципе, навряд ли ее там можно будет сделать. В общем, отвечайте по теме, пожалуйста...

Comment: Прямой перевод вашего кода на русский 

    ...
    if ($row1 == $row2 && $row1 == $row3 && $row1 == $row4 or die('ошибка')) {
        echo $row1;
    }


    Получить поле "описание" по переменным
    Если все описания равны - вывести первое.

Собственно, а что вы от него хотели?

Comment: Ну я и спрашиваю, как там надо изменить код, чтобы все работало нормально?

Comment: Попробовал сделать так: 

<code>if (
$row1 == $row2 &&
$row1 == $row3 &&
$row1 == $row4
) {
echo $row1, $row2, $row3, $row4;
}
</code>

В итоге вывелось 4 одинаковых слова.

Comment: А вы наверно ёлочку ожидали...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте понять что делает такой код:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res))
        $row1 = $row->opisanie;
```

Зачем вам вытаскивать по 2 записи???

```
SELECT `opisanie` FROM `parte` where minimum='100' limit 0,2
```

Зачем вам столько переменных?

P.S.

```
$terh = $_POST['tema'];
$jui  = $_POST['min'];
$uti  = $_POST['form'];
$reui = $_POST['vyp'] or die("Что-то не так.");

if (
    preg_match("/были/", $reui) &&
    preg_match("/^игры/", $terh) &&
    preg_match("/^100/", $jui) &&
    preg_match("/^topline/", $uti)
) {
  $dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
  mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");
  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

  $res = mysql_query("
    SELECT `parte`.`opisanie`
    FROM `parte`, `bada`
    WHERE
      `parte`.`vyp` = 'были' AND
      `parte`.`minimum` = '100' AND
      `bada`.`format` = 'top' AND
      `bada`.`tema` = 'игры' AND
      `parte`.`opisanie` = `bada`.`opisanie`
  ") or die("Что-то не так.");

  while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object($res) ) echo $row->opisanie.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Пока в ванной был мысль в голову пришла: надо все запросы к MySQL объединить, захожу сюда и вижу, что уже здесь все готовое!))

timka_s, спасибо большое за помощь, почти на все мои вопросы Вы отвечаете. 

<strong>Хотелось бы попросить администрацию сайта поощрять таких людей!</strong>

Comment: А Вы сами (пункт **'наградить'**) под ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменть `mysql_fetch_object` на `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: Попробовал - одно и тоже.